# PayPal Parallel vs Chained

Tags: api, paypal, payment, chained

I understand Parallel payments are limited to 6 receivers but what about Chained, it only says multiple receivers.

We plan on having many items in our catalog and know that many will purchase more than 6 items, each items will be split by 4 , 1 will be developer but what if you had 12 items that 3+(1*12) which would be 15 receivers. Is there a way to do this?

Also can you have each account pay their own amount on the fees or does the primary get stuck with the whole thing?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

The Pay call in general is limited to 6 receivers.  PayPal may be able to open that up for you but you'd have to discuss that with them during the process of applying and getting your live App ID for your app.

When working with the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) you can use the feesPayer element to specify how to handle the fees.

If Adaptive Payments -> Pay simply won't work out for you, you could go ahead and setup a regular checkout system where the buyer sends you all the money, and then you could automate the process of sending money from that out to the people who need it from the order using an [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) solution.

You'd still be limited to 6 receivers in a Pay request, but you could make multiple Pay requests within your IPN script.  Alternatively, you could use the [MassPay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/) to send money to up to 250 people at a time.

With MassPay, though, the sender pays the fee, but the max fee no matter how much the amount is would be $1.00.  You could simply work that (and the original payment fee) into your deal with your partners so that the fees get split up accordingly.